# Simple Sound Player

Tags: c, playsound

I am trying to make a simple app that plays a sound when pressing a specific number but whatever I enter it plays the first song for some weird reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "MMsystem.h"

void main(void){

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tCh00se A M3m3\n\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t1.Quick Maths\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t2.Crippling Deprresion");

    int MemeNumber;
    scanf_s("%d", &MemeNumber);
    if (MemeNumber = "1")
    {
        PlaySound(TEXT("BigShaq.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
    }

    if (MemeNumber = '2')
    {
        PlaySound(TEXT("CripplinD.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`if (MemeNumber = "1")`

1. MemeNumber is an `int` and `"1"` is a `char*/string`
2. `=` is an assignment, not a compare.

`if (MemeNumber = '2')`

1. MemNumber is an `int`and `'2'` is a char.
2. `=` is an assignment not a compare.

Try `if (MemeNumber == 1)` and `if (MemeNumber == 2)`. Also: have a look at the switch statement. It will help simplify your code.

Note: If you compiled with all the warnings turned on, the compiler would highlight all of this for you.